# Python json: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) in Python application

Tags: python, json

I have searched around however none of the solutions have worked. I have a WSGI application currently using Flask on Python. I am attempting to parse a json file that was also created using the json library in Python at another app route. Here is how I am reading and attempting to parse the file.

```
 with open("data/accounts/names/" + username + ".json", "r+") as read_file:
            uid = json.load(read_file)
```

This is the contents of the file

```
{"username": "username", "name": "Name", "uid": "227072665949", "following": [""], "followers": [""], "posts": [""], "joined": [""], "device": "835527195310", "liked": [""]}
```

This is the full error message

```
ERROR in app: Exception on /api/loginuser [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\##\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\##\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\##\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\##\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\##\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\##\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "D:\##\Desktop\stella\xick\app.py", line 62, in logat
    uid = json.load(read_file)
  File "C:\Users\##\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\##\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\##\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\##\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Additionally, I have noticed whenever I attempt to run the code, it keeps getting wiped, I have also tried:

```
uidfile = open("data/accounts/names/" + username + ".json", "r")
uid = json.loads(uidfile.read())
```

but get the same response. I have also tried using a linter to validate my json and no problems seem to arise. The file is encoded in utf-8 and seems to be fine when I try print() on its contents.

Answer (score 0):

You mostly likely have a null byte at the beginning of the file.

Here's what that looks like with a simpler test file with a null byte inserted at the front:

```
$ od -ba test.json
0000000 000 173 042 165 163 145 162 156 141 155 145 042 072 040 042 165
        nul   {   "   u   s   e   r   n   a   m   e   "   :  sp   "   u
0000020 163 145 162 156 141 155 145 042 175 012
          s   e   r   n   a   m   e   "   }  nl

$ python3
>>> import json
>>> with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
...     j = json.load(f)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
>>>
```

Remove the leading null, and you should be fine.